# 2 dimensional array of object error

Tags: java, arrays, object

i cant use the array of object for class Table . Class table has nothin in it exept the value and 2 functions return and set , in main i have only create an object of game what does it seems wrong to you?
error given is::

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Game.check_me(Game.java:33)   at Game.(Game.java:19)    at
>   Main.main(Main.java:7) Java Result: 1

that's what i am talking about it gives me an error for the array :/

```
import java.util.Random;


public  class Game {
    private static final int r = 3;
    private static final int w = 4;
    private  Table1[][] table;
    private final String CHAR_LIST= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public Game(){
        this.table = new Table1 [r][w];

        char value;
        //table[2][1].display_value();here is the problem
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                value=generateRandomChar();
                if(check_me(value))
                    table[i][j].set_value(value);//here is the problem
                else{
                    while(check_me(value))
                        value=generateRandomChar();
                    table[i][j].set_value(value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private boolean check_me(char value){
    for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<table[i].length; j++){
        char ch=table[i][j].return_Value();
            if(ch==value)
            return false;
        }}
    return true;
}

public void display_table(){
    for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<table[i].length; j++){
            table[i][j].display_value();
    System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
private char generateRandomChar(){
int number = getRandomNumber();
        char ch = CHAR_LIST.charAt(number);           
        return ch;
    }

private int getRandomNumber() {
        int randomInt = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(CHAR_LIST.length());
        if (randomInt - 1 == -1) {
            return randomInt;
        } else {
            return randomInt - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to claim an error in the title, but don't mention what it is or where it's happening. Can you please revise your question to include these details? Any additional information you can give us as well would be helpful when answering your question.

Comment: sure one sec but dont expect much i cant understand this error :/

Comment: If you don't understand the error, you should Google it to make an effort to understand what it is, why it's happening, if someone else has encountered the error and has a solution you might be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the comments of tnw (including which type of error you get and the implementation of Table1 class).

So far I think you will get a NullPointerException.
Because you initialize your array with new Table1[r][w].

The next thing you do is accessing them in the for loops. But you haven't filled the array in code given above. At the moment you access them with table[i][j].set_value(value) the value of table[i][j] is null.

---

```
public Game(){
    this.table = new Table1 [r][w];


  //fix for your problem
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        this.table[i][j] = new Table1();
    }
  }


    char value;
    //table[2][1].display_value();here is the problem
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            value=generateRandomChar();
            if(check_me(value))
                table[i][j].set_value(value);//here is the problem
            else{
                while(check_me(value))
                    value=generateRandomChar();
                table[i][j].set_value(value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

(Dear motivated editors, I would be happy if you leave my code snippets inline).